# How to match the map in Rviz with real world map?

Tags: ros, nav2d, nav2d-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using Nav2d simulator and launching tutorial2 file. I have changed the original map to another simplified map and using real robot instead of Stage. The problem is that an object is located in left side in real world but in Rviz it shows in right side!
I have been looking in configuration file tutorial2.rviz to find a parameter to change (flip over) but I'm not sure which parameter should I change if it already exist !?  Or can I do that while Rviz is running ?

[C:\fakepath\RvizMap.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14624450548239088.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233668/how-to-match-the-map-in-rviz-with-real-world-map?/) by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2016-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can it be that your laser is mounted upside down? I that case you'll have to reflect that in the transformation from body to laser. (defined somewhere in your robot setup, not nav2d)

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2016-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on 2016-05-06**:
Yes it is mounted upside down to robot. It makes vary good since now. And I solved the problem. Thanks :D